# Error append column to the end of an existng excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to append the column to the end of an existing excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in c#, I use Microsoft excel 2007, here is my code:

```
   public void UpdateExcel_MSInterop(
        string ExcelFile)
        {
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;

            Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
            try
            {

                //define ms excel application
                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                //
                int Hwnd = xlApp.Hwnd;

                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                //
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile, Type.Missing, true);

                int SheetIndex = 1;
                foreach (Worksheet objSHT in xlWorkbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    if (SheetIndex == 1)// ExcelSheetFullName.Substring(0, ExcelSheetFullName.Length - 1))
                    {
                        Range rng = objSHT.UsedRange;

                        int colCount = rng.Columns.Count;
                        int rowCount = rng.Rows.Count;

                        Range newRng = objSHT.get_Range(objSHT.Cells[1, 1], objSHT.Cells[1, colCount]).EntireColumn.Insert(Missing.Value,XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);

                        newRng.Cells[1, colCount + 1] = "State";
                        for (int r = 2; r <= rowCount; r++)
                        {
                            newRng.Cells[r, colCount + 1] = Products.Rows[r - 2]["state"].ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    SheetIndex++;
                }
                xlWorkbook.Save();

                if (xlWorkbook != null)
                    xlWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:true);

                if (xlApp != null)
                    xlApp.Quit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (xlWorkbook != null)
                    xlWorkbook.Close();

                if (xlApp != null)
                    xlApp.Quit();

                xlWorkbook = null;
                xlApp = null;

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I get error:

```
object dose not contain a definition for get_Range
```

How to fix this error, or if my approach is wrong how to append column to the end of an existing excel file,please give me example,Thanks for help.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet doesn't have a function get_Range. You're probably looking for [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.range?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Worksheet_Range_System_Object_System_Object_).

Comment: ok, so how to modify my code to append column to the end of an existing excel file?

Comment: You don't need to "append" a new column - just write values to the Cells or Range properties.

Comment: i try as you said add value to cells  rng.Cells[1, colCount + 1] = "State";, no error happen , but did not save any changes, please review my code

Comment: i found the problem xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile, Type.Missing, true); sholud be xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile, Type.Missing, false); and it save changes,thanks